# Insert form Data in Django Database

Tags: django

When I try to insert form data into the django database, I get an error on calling the function `save()`.

`form.save() AttributeError: 'FormName' object has no attribute 'save'`

Can anyone help me to understand why this object does not have attribute save?

Comment: You are not using [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: i am using form.py and models.py for model and register my models in admin.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form object is not a ModelForm, or Model Object.  Your speculation of calling  a save() on form may be logical, however, it doesn't talk to the Database directly.

In the simplest manner, if you need to insert into the database using Django's ORM, you will need to create a subclass of `ModelForm`, or `Model`. They usually map to a single database table. Like this from [Django's official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/):

```
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author # specify model which talks to database.
        fields = ['name', 'title', 'birth_date']
```

In AuthorForm class,  you also specify the model in meta.  You can define the model like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You should keep the above classes `AuthorForm` and `Author` in two different .py files for modularity.

Comment: In which file i create ModelForm class??

Comment: updated my answer, let me know if it solves your issue.